# Changing Redirect After Form Submittal

Tags: php, html, wordpress, forms, url

On my Wordpress website I have users fill out a form which ultimately generates a product. One of the form fields is a "Title" for the product. I'm trying to change the redirect for where the user is sent after they submit the form.

The URL for products are based on the "Title" of the product (e.g. http://example.com/product/My-Great-Product-Title/)

The issue with my current code is that I get a returned URL of... http://example.com/product/My%Great%Product%Title/

This returns a page not found 404 error.

Naturally a product title with no spaces in between the words works just fine but for obvious reasons every title can't be limited to one word.

My current code for redirecting which results with the 404 error...

$redirect = "http://example.com/product/$title";

How can I get my URL to be "My-Great-Product-Title" instead of "My%Great%Product%Title" which doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the URL is generated by WordPress whenever the Product is created and now created by some other method you should be able to use [`sanitize_title()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_title/) which is what WordPress uses to create their friendly permalinks.

The drawback to this is if there's a duplicate, it won't detect this but WordPress will append a `-2` to the url. A better solution would be to get the ID after the product has been created and use [`get_permalink()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_permalink/) which will be more accurate.

Comment: Thanks for the help but I actually came across another fix. I used str_replace(); to replace the spaces in the users $title with dashes and it worked!